# matplotlibを用いた際に軸の数字が表示されない問題について

Tags: python, matplotlib

matplotlibを用いたグラフを作成した際に、y軸の目盛りが表示されずに困っています。以下のようなコードを用いて、y軸がログスケールになるようなグラフを作りたいのですがグラフを表示してみるとy軸の目盛りが何も表示されません。

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
with open("hoge.csv", 'r') as f:
    list = []
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        list.append(float(line[0]))

plt.yscale("log")
plt.plot(list)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("x", fontsize = 15)
plt.ylabel("y", fontsize = 15)
plt.show()
```

hoge.csvの中身は以下のようになっています。

```
125853.0904
125844.9593
125843.4201
125842.9831
125842.7985
125842.7672
125842.6343
125842.4554
125842.4153
125842.3786
```

このように値が大きくあまり変化しない場合、y軸の目盛りが表示されないような仕様なのでしょうか。解決策などあればお教えいただけるとありがたいです。
こちらの環境は
OS:windows7
python:3.5
matplotlib:2.0.2
となっています。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

手っ取り早い方法は次のようにyticksを指定する方法です。

```
plt.yticks(range(125840,125854))
```

[image: Y軸のtickを指定]

丁寧にやるなら英語版の[この回答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188757/matplotlib-specify-format-of-floats-for-tick-lables)をご参考ください。